# How to keep WIFI alive while application is streaming audio in the background in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, java-native-interface, audiotrack

I have a streaming audio application on Android which uses `AudioTrack` and `track.write()`.

After somewhile, audio was stoppping. I couldn't find the problem. After that, I saw that Admob also receives an exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to googleads.g.doubleclick.net:.. connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

After seeing this line in the logs, I thought that there is an instability related to device's wi-fi connection. (I use Galaxy S3 4.1.2)

Since I use the same connection on my desktop, I can say that internet has no problems (i can stream the same audio on desktop).

This does not occur in the same time period. It happens randomly between 10 secs to 10 minutes.

What can be the reason and can I prevent this by telling operating system to not close the connection? (I am already using it in a Foreground process)

**Updates:**
I tried the following lock but the problem continues.

```
    private static WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) AppMain.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
        .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "plywilock");
```

I set this inside my MyPlayerInSameProcessService where I release it onDestroy() of service. Code gets audio data c++ with jni and feeds AudioTrack at java side.

If I disable Wi-Fi, it workds perfectly and smoothly without any interruption on 3G.

In the same Wi-Fi network, if I use another application with the same url I use in my application, that application works smoothly. So, probably it's me, not the Wi-Fi quality.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

Comment: Thank you, however, it did not work and I updated my question with the latest details.